# OK Google Voice Match not working

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-8, google-assistant, ok-google

On my Samsung Galaxy S8, my phone no longer responds when I say "OK Google"

The voice match settings don't work, I found device-specific settings and can attempt to set voice match up there, but when it does voice training and I say "OK Google" it does not proceed.

EDIT:
I didn't have S Voice installed. Bixby is a stock app and I don't think I enabled it on this (or any of my) phone(s). I worked before regardless. I'll double check anyway. I uninstalled Alexa and Cortana. Updated Google App and all permissions were enabled. I toggled the Microphone option off and back on. Google Assistant app said no permissions required. Still the same result unfortunately.

Comment: I'm having exact same experience, seems to have started following recent Google app update. I'm also on an S8. Any luck?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Bixby or S Voice installed and would prefer to use Google's voice assistant instead, your best bet might be to disable Bixby or S Voice on your device entirely. And if you’ve downloaded Alexa, Cortana, or any other voice assistant on your phone, either disable or delete it.
Also, make sure the Google app is updated to the latest version. Also make sure to grant all permissions for the Google app by going to Settings > Apps > Google app > Permissions (the path may differ from model to model)

Comment: I didn't have S Voice installed. Bixby is a stock app and I don't think I enabled it on this (or any of my) phone(s). I worked before regardless. I'll double check anyway. I uninstalled Alexa and Cortana. Updated Google App and all permissions were enabled. I toggled the Microphone option off and back on. Google Assistant app said no permissions required. Still the same result unfortunately.